# Как скачать страницу через selenium

Tags: python, selenium, bs4

мне нужно скачать страницу которую открыл selenium для дальнейшего парсинга через bs4. Как такое сделать?

Comment: Requests может скачать, селениум тут не при чем. Парсить — bs4.

Comment: мне нужно именна та страница которую открыл selenium, т.к мне нужны данный с изменёной страницы(на кнопки некоторые нажал).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-get-html/

```py
#_*_coding: utf-8_*_

from selenium import webdriver
import time

# start web browser
browser=webdriver.Firefox()

# get source code
browser.get("https://en.wikipedia.org")
html = browser.page_source
time.sleep(2)
print(html)

# close web browser
browser.close()
```

И кстати, как вы через requests парсить будете?

Comment: извиняюсь, выразился не корректно. Всё же requests для получение страницы, для парсинга юзается bs4. Но спасибо за ответ

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/213987)